# Difference between 0.0.0.0 and * in routing table

Tags: linux, routing, opensuse

I have two webservers. Webserver **A** has this route (`netstat -r`):

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.40.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

and Webserver **B** has this route instead:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.40.0    *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Is there a difference?

I have timeout problems while trying to connect my netbeans with xdebug on webserver **A** and get "Waiting for Connection" in netbeans which stays forever, is it related to the route?

**Update:**

Output of `ip route list`:

Webserver **A**:

```
default via 192.168.40.20 dev eth0
192.168.40.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.40.44
```

Webserver **B**:

```
default via 192.168.40.20 dev eth0
192.168.40.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.40.47
```

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: I am using openSUSE Linux

Comment: So don't use the deprecated tools (`ifconfig`, `route`). Check the output of `ip route list` and you will see the difference. Paste the output into the question. Also you can resolve the actual route with `ip route get <dst>` command. Try to use it to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post. The only different is the src address at the end.

Comment: Seems like you have different versions of `netstat`. Check the output of `netstat --version`. There isn't the difference between routing configuration.

Comment: The difference in the source address attribute is related with assigned address on the `eth0` interface, not more else.

Comment: @AntonDanilov, You are right, Server A has net-tools 2.10-alpha and Server B has netstat 1.4.2

Comment: Ok, so there is no difference. The xdebug connection problem has nothing to do with the routing table. Thx! :)

Comment: Check the firewall. Run the `tcpdump` to troubleshoot the connectivity issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't use the deprecated tools like `ifconfig`, `route` and so on. Use the tools from `iproute` package.

   - `ip route list` - to check the routing table
   - `ip route get <dst>` - resolve the actual route - the packets to the specified destination will go through this route.
2. The difference in the output is related with different versions of `netstat` tool.
3. The routing configuration on the hosts is the same.
4. To troubleshoot the connectivity issues you can use the `tcpdump` at first step.